# Is the Dirac measure outer regular on a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space with its Borel sigma algebra. Let $\delta _x$ be a Dirac measure. Is it true that the Dirac measure is outer regular i.e. $\delta _x (E)= \inf \{\delta_x (U) : E \subseteq U , U \text{ is open}\}$ for any measurable set $E$ ?

I know it is inner regular since the singleton $\{x\}$ is compact.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\in E$ the formula $1=\delta_x(E)=\inf \{\delta_x(U):E\subseteq U, U \text{ open}\}$ holds because $x\in U$ for every relevant $U$ and so $\delta_x(U)=1$.
If $x\notin E$, take the set $U=X\backslash \{x\}$ (open because $\{x\}$ is closed because $X$ is Hausdorff).